# what is meant by Newtonian Polytrope?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, astrophysics, neutron-stars, stellar-physics

I study about newtonian polytrope n = 1 that for this polytrope steller radius does not depend on mass and central density.
I want to know are there some more polytropes that are known as newtonian polytrope and what the general properties the newtonian polytrope contain.

Comment: Please give the context. Probably it means considering a polytrope of $n=1$ with Newtonian gravitation and hydrostatic equilibrium (as opposed to using the TOV equation).

Comment: http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/319702/pdf. "To understand the relative insensitivity of the radius to
the mass for normal neutron stars, it is relevant that a Newtonian
polytrope with n = 1 has the property that the stellar
radius is independent of both the mass and central density."

Answer (score 0):

A polytrope with $n=1$ has $P \propto \rho^2$, where $P$ is the pressure and $\rho$ is the density.

Using a *Newtonian* version of the equation of hydrostatic equilibrium, it is straightforward to establish a form of the virial theorem.
$$ \Omega = - 3 \int P\ dV = -3 \int \frac{P}{\rho}\ dm,$$
where $\Omega$ is the gravitational potential energy and $dm$ is a mass shell.

For the sake of deriving mass-radius proportionalities, make the horrible approximation that $\rho$ is a constant, so $\Omega = -3GM^2/5R$ (a density gradient only changes numerical factors). Then if $P=A\rho^2$
$$ \frac{GM^2}{5R} = \int A\rho\ dm = A\rho M = \frac{4\pi M^2}{3R^3}$$
and thus we see $R$ has a fixed constant value that is independent of mass. And, since density depends on mass and radius, this means the radius must also be independent of the density.

In a General Relativistic (rather than Newtonian) formalism, this does not happen because the pressure also contributes to the right hand side of the [Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_equation) equation of hydrostatic equilibrium. Therefore the equilibrium radius of a star whose pressure depends on density cannot be independent of mass or density in GR. However, I think the point the paper is trying to make is that at high densities inside neutron stars, the equation of state is approximately $P = A\rho^2$, so they do behave like Newtonian $n=1$ polytropes until the density/pressure becomes too high to ignore GR, and this is the reason why most mass-radius relationships have a "vertical" piece with an almost constant radius over a range of masses.

The properties of polytropes ae described on the relevant [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytrope) page. Perhaps the most notable are that $n=\infty$ corresponds to an isothermal sphere and that an $n=5$ polytrope has an infinite radius. The higher the value of $n$ the more centrally concentrated the body is.